# Sort and select from a complex nested dictionary using heapq

Tags: python, python-3.x, heapq

I have the following nested dictionary:

```
a={'2020-12-08':
        {'navi.o_efx': {'coint_value': 0.923033, 'hl_value': 0.475025},
        'stm.n_efx': {'coint_value': 0.915424, 'hl_value': 0.294162},
        'kioo.o_efx': {'coint_value': 0.92575, 'hl_value': 0.369817}},
   '2020-09-24':
        {'navi.o_qrvo.o': {'coint_value': 0.919749, 'hl_value': 0.215322},
        'qrvo.o_efx': {'coint_value': 0.976447, 'hl_value': 0.11208},
        'navi.o_stm.n': {'coint_value': 0.974414, 'hl_value': 0.168408},
        'qrvo.o_stm.n': {'coint_value': 0.964797, 'hl_value': 0.14407},
        'stm.n_efx': {'coint_value': 0.935519, 'hl_value': 0.166952}},
   '2020-11-01':
       {'qrvo.o_stm.n': {'coint_value': 0.95096, 'hl_value': 0.104152}}
   }
```

I wanted to use heapq to sort on the basis of **'hl_value'** and chose the smallest 2 sub-dictionaries for a particular date. For example, the final output should be as below:

```
a={'2020-12-08':
        {'stm.n_efx': {'coint_value': 0.915424, 'hl_value': 0.294162},
        'kioo.o_efx': {'coint_value': 0.92575, 'hl_value': 0.369817}},
   '2020-09-24':
        {'qrvo.o_efx': {'coint_value': 0.976447, 'hl_value': 0.11208},
        'qrvo.o_stm.n': {'coint_value': 0.964797, 'hl_value': 0.14407}},
   '2020-11-01':
       {'qrvo.o_stm.n': {'coint_value': 0.95096, 'hl_value': 0.104152}}
   }
```

I tried using the below code, but doesn't seem to work :

```
for k, v in a.items():
    for i_k, i_v in v.items():
        a[k][i_k] = dict(heapq.nsmallest(2, i_v.items(), key=i_v['hl_value']))
```

Comment: (1) Generally you should be more specific than "doesn't work". Indentation of code should be proper, too. (2) The key parameter must be a function to extract the sort key from an item to sort (see the docs).

Comment: @MichaelButscher: Thanks for your reply. Indentation was meant for the reader to understand the dictionary in a single glance. I am sorry if this was confusing. Secondly, I did try writing the code and attached the sample code. I thought that pasting the error message would make the query look  clumsy and jumbled up.

Comment: I meant the indentation of the code at the bottom which wouldn't be accepted by the Python interpreter, the dictionary assignment is usefully and correctly indented. Complete error messages with full tracebacks (which should be also formatted as "code" on this site) are valuable and often necessary information. For these actual three lines of code both isn't strictly necessary but good practice.

Comment: Point noted :). I have corrected the indentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here using [heapq.nsmallest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest):

```
import heapq

a = {
    '2020-12-08':
        {
            'navi.o_efx': {'coint_value': 0.923033, 'hl_value': 0.475025},
            'stm.n_efx': {'coint_value': 0.915424, 'hl_value': 0.294162},
            'kioo.o_efx': {'coint_value': 0.92575, 'hl_value': 0.369817}
        },
   '2020-09-24':
        {
            'navi.o_qrvo.o': {'coint_value': 0.919749, 'hl_value': 0.215322},
            'qrvo.o_efx': {'coint_value': 0.976447, 'hl_value': 0.11208},
            'navi.o_stm.n': {'coint_value': 0.974414, 'hl_value': 0.168408},
            'qrvo.o_stm.n': {'coint_value': 0.964797, 'hl_value': 0.14407},
            'stm.n_efx': {'coint_value': 0.935519, 'hl_value': 0.166952}
        },
   '2020-11-01':
        {
            'qrvo.o_stm.n': {'coint_value': 0.95096, 'hl_value': 0.104152}
        }
}


for key in a:
    result = heapq.nsmallest(2, a[key].items(), key=lambda value: value[1]['hl_value'])
    a[key] = dict(result)

print(a)
```

**Output**

```
{'2020-12-08': {'stm.n_efx': {'coint_value': 0.915424, 'hl_value': 0.294162}, 'kioo.o_efx': {'coint_value': 0.92575, 'hl_value': 0.369817}}, '2020-09-24': {'qrvo.o_efx': {'coint_value': 0.976447, 'hl_value': 0.11208}, 'qrvo.o_stm.n': {'coint_value': 0.964797, 'hl_value': 0.14407}}, '2020-11-01': {'qrvo.o_stm.n': {'coint_value': 0.95096, 'hl_value': 0.104152}}}
```

**Output** (pretty printed via `print(json.dumps(a, indent=4))`):

```
{
    "2020-12-08": {
        "stm.n_efx": {
            "coint_value": 0.915424,
            "hl_value": 0.294162
        },
        "kioo.o_efx": {
            "coint_value": 0.92575,
            "hl_value": 0.369817
        }
    },
    "2020-09-24": {
        "qrvo.o_efx": {
            "coint_value": 0.976447,
            "hl_value": 0.11208
        },
        "qrvo.o_stm.n": {
            "coint_value": 0.964797,
            "hl_value": 0.14407
        }
    },
    "2020-11-01": {
        "qrvo.o_stm.n": {
            "coint_value": 0.95096,
            "hl_value": 0.104152
        }
    }
}
```